# How is different unbounded and bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

#Here graph will be create most likely same but how Q1. will be Unbounded and Q2. will be Bounded

Q$1$

How is it an Unbounded LPP?

$$\max z = 30 x + 15 y$$
Subject to
$$4 x + 6 y \ge 12$$
$$4 x + 1 y \ge 4$$
$$x,y \ge 0$$

Q$2$

How is it a Bounded LPP?

$$\max z = 2 x + 3 y$$
Subject to
$$2 x + 2 y \ge 14$$
$$6 x + 8 y \ge 48$$
$$x,y \ge 0$$

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Both are unbounded.

Comment: For the first $Q_1$   plot in DESMOS the following
$$2x+2y\ge6 \{x\ge0\}\{y\ge0\}\\4x+y\ge4 \{x\ge0\}\{y\ge0\}$$ Then, in the shadow region (which is the corresponding intersection) examine  possible values of $30x+15y$.

Similarly with $Q_2$.

Comment: Q.2 in my book. Calculated the value of Max Z: And in Q1 it was said that it is unbounded while the graph of both is being made on the outside. That's why I'm confused.Which one would be correct and how?

Answer (score 0):

Both linear models are unbounded. Looking at the constraints of both programs, we have
\begin{matrix}
4 x + 6 y \ge 12 & \text{and} & 4 x + 1 y \ge 4\\
2 x + 2 y \ge 14 &  & 6 x + 8 y \ge 48
\end{matrix}

both do not include a constraint to cap their limits as $x$ and $y$ increase.

Observe that this is the feasible region of the first question model:

[image: 1]

Observe that this is the feasible region of the second question model:

[image: 2]

Confirming the issues mentioned above regarding nothing closing the feasible region. If the problem were to be minimized within these feasible regions, then this would be a non-issue.